# Fetch status of a container within a container under Kubernetes pod

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am using a NVIDIA Clara Deploy SDK which works on Kubernetes cluster. It provides the pipeline from E2E Medical image analysis (acquisition to analysis/segmentation). As I am using this, the E2E flow doesn't work. Because the output from one of the containers within the pod is empty. Though I am able to get the logs of a main containers, I am not sure how to get the logs of containers which are running within a specific container?.

I executed the below command through online research and this lists down the images,

```
sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" |tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |sort |uniq -c
```

[image]

Later, I execute this command and it lists down the containers within this pod

```
sudo kubectl describe pod clara-clara-platform-7bb6f9f5c6-pdzgd
```

This lists down 5 containers in the pod

1) Inference server
2) Dicom-server
3) Render-server
4) Clara-core
5)Clara-dashboard

But clara has containers within containers. That's how I have understood it.not sure whether I am right.

Sharing the doc below for your reference. I guess all the above containers images are part of main "Clara-core" container. How do I get the status of sub containers within a main container?

[image]

When I try to get the logs of the above containers, I don't see any info regarding what happened when the ai-container (applastchannel) was executed?

Please note that I would like to get the status of ai-container which is "applastchannel" in my case

Here is YAML file

```
apiVersion: v1
 items:
 - apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  generateName: clara-clara-platform-7bb6f9f5c6-
  labels:
   app.kubernetes.io/instance: clara
   app.kubernetes.io/name: clara-platform
  pod-template-hash: 7bb6f9f5c6
ownerReferences:
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  blockOwnerDeletion: true
  controller: true
  kind: ReplicaSet
  name: clara-clara-platform-7bb6f9f5c6
  uid: d0f0dc14-8b7e-45e3-8528-0879c7ce9330
selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/clara-clara-platform-7bb6f9f5c6- 
 pdzgd
  spec:
   containers:
   - args:
   - --model-store=/models
   command:
   - trtserver
   image: clara/trtis:0.1.8
   imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
   livenessProbe:
    failureThreshold: 3
    httpGet:
      path: /api/health/live
      port: 8000
      scheme: HTTP
     initialDelaySeconds: 5
     periodSeconds: 5
     successThreshold: 1
     timeoutSeconds: 1
   name: inference-server
   ports:
   - containerPort: 8000
     protocol: TCP
   - containerPort: 8001
     protocol: TCP
   - containerPort: 8002
     protocol: TCP
   readinessProbe:
     failureThreshold: 3
     httpGet:
       path: /api/health/ready
      port: 8000
      scheme: HTTP
     initialDelaySeconds: 5
     periodSeconds: 5
     successThreshold: 1
     timeoutSeconds: 1
   resources: {}
   securityContext:
     runAsUser: 1000
   terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
   terminationMessagePolicy: File
  volumeMounts:
   - mountPath: /models
    name: pv-clara-volume
    subPath: models
   - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
    name: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
    readOnly: true
 - image: clara/dicomserver:0.1.8
   imagePullPolicy: Never
   name: dicom-server
   ports:
  - containerPort: 104
    hostPort: 104
    name: dicom-port
    protocol: TCP
  resources: {}
  terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /payloads
    name: pv-clara-volume
    subPath: clara-core/payloads
  - mountPath: /app/app.yaml
    name: dicom-server-config
    subPath: app.yaml
  - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
    name: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
    readOnly: true
- image: clara/core:0.1.8
  imagePullPolicy: Never
  name: clara-core
  ports:
  - containerPort: 50051
    protocol: TCP
  resources: {}
  terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /app/Jobs
    name: pv-clara-volume
    subPath: clara-core/payloads
  - mountPath: /app/Workflows
    name: pv-clara-volume
    subPath: clara-core/workflows
  - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
    name: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
    readOnly: true
- image: clara/clara-dashboard:0.1.8
  imagePullPolicy: Never
  name: clara-dashboard
  ports:
  - containerPort: 8080
    hostPort: 8080
    name: dashboard-port
    protocol: TCP
  resources: {}
  terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
    name: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
    readOnly: true
- image: clara/renderserver:0.1.8
  imagePullPolicy: Never
  name: render-server
  ports:
  - containerPort: 2050
    hostPort: 2050
    name: render-port
    protocol: TCP
  resources: {}
  terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /app/datasets
    name: pv-clara-volume
    subPath: datasets
  - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
    name: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
    readOnly: true
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
enableServiceLinks: true
imagePullSecrets:
- name: nvcr.io
nodeName: whiskey
priority: 0
restartPolicy: Always
schedulerName: default-scheduler
securityContext: {}
serviceAccount: clara-service-account
serviceAccountName: clara-service-account
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
tolerations:
- effect: NoExecute
  key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
  operator: Exists
  tolerationSeconds: 300
- effect: NoExecute
  key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
  operator: Exists
  tolerationSeconds: 300
volumes:
- name: pv-clara-volume
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: pv-clara-volume-claim
- configMap:
    defaultMode: 420
    items:
    - key: app.Release.yaml
      path: app.yaml
    name: clara-configmap
  name: dicom-server-config
- name: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
  secret:
    defaultMode: 420
    secretName: clara-service-account-token-c62fp
  status:
 phase: Pending
 qosClass: BestEffort
 kind: List
 metadata:
 resourceVersion: ""
 selfLink: ""
```

Can you help me achieve this?

Comment: can you simply share kubernetes deployment manifest?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Hi, I updated the post

Comment: I am marking the below answer as solution because the discussion helped me to figure out the answer and commands also helped me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the yaml I see only these containers in the pod:

```
Image:                          Name:
clara/core:0.1.8                clara-core
clara/clara-dashboard:0.1.8     clara-dashboard
clara/renderserver:0.1.8        render-server
clara/trtis:0.1.8               inference-server
clara/dicomserver:0.1.8         dicom-server
```

I'm not sure which one is the one you need, nothing seems to be called AI, but either way you can check logs with:

```
kubectl logs clara-clara-platform-7bb6f9f5c6-pdzgd %container_name%
```

so if `inference-server` is the one you are interested in:

```
kubectl logs clara-clara-platform-7bb6f9f5c6-pdzgd inference-server
```

Comment: Actually that's my question. But if you see the doc "Bundled containers", there are few more containers like dicom-reader, dicom-writer, ai-container. How do I get the status of those?

Comment: But you can see in my post at the top that there are few more images like "applastchannel", "dicom-reader", "dicom-writer". These gets fired up as well but don't know how to track them. Believe these all are part of clara-core container.

Comment: well, that means they are part of other pods, not the one you showed, just look at all the pods one by one and you will find the ones you are looking. I cant really do that for you. you can use `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and start there, or add `-o yaml` and do some grepping

Comment: No, I was only looking for a way to know how to do this. Will check the other pods. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: well, because you see them as part of the output of the first command in the question, it means they are actually pods on kubernetes. they are just part of other pods, which you didn't show

Comment: Much appreciate your inputs. Will do a check.

Comment: But what I don't get is, the doc says that clara core spins up other containers in the workflow (dicom-reader, dicom-writer etc). Whereas clara core is part of the pod (clara-clara-platform) but can the dicom-reader and dicom-writer be part of other pods then? Shouldn't it be part of the same pod?

Comment: well, it might spin up other pods, i have no idea about this particular solution. this pod is using a security context, which might have permissions to do that